# jSoup get title from img tag

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I have a scenario where I need to pull the title from a img tag like below.

```
<img alt="Bear" border="0" src="/images/teddy/5433.gif" title="Bear"/>
```

I was able to get the image url. But how do i get the title from the img tag.
From above title = "bear". I want to extract this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Element#attr()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#attr%28java.lang.String%29) to extract arbitrary element attributes.

```
Element img = selectItSomehow();
String title = img.attr("title");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [Jsoup Cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/) - [Extract attributes, text, and HTML from elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

Answer (score 0):

```
String html = "<img alt='Bear' border='0' src='/images/teddy/5433.gif' title='Bear'/>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element e = doc.select("img[title]").first();
String title = e.attr("title");
System.out.println(title);
```