# Get Image title with JSOUP

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

i have this table.

```
<div id="activeArrivi">
    <div class="aggBox">
        <label>Ultimo aggiornamento:</label> <span class="update">21/05/2015 15:25</span>
    </div>

    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Compagnia</th>
            <th>n.</th>
            <th>Provenienza</th>
            <th>Schedulato</th>
            <th>Stimato</th>
            <th>Stato</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                        <tr id="a0" style="background-color: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.8);">
                <td>
                    <img class="company" alt="RYANAIR" src="/img/RYANAIR.png" original-title="RYANAIR">                 </td>
                <td>05021</td>
                <td>Roma Fiumicino</td>
                <td>21/05/2015 14                       :30</td>
                <td>21/05/2015 14                       :45</td>
                <td>
                                            <img src="/images/volo_green.gif" alt="Atterrato" title="Atterrato"><br> Atterrato                  </td>
            </tr>
                        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

here there is my code:

```
  doc = Jsoup.connect("http:/url").timeout(10*1000).get();


            Element table = doc.select("table").first();
            Iterator<Element> iterator = table.select("td").iterator();

            //iterator.next(); // first one is image, skip it

            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                arrivi++;

                A_Compagnia[arrivi] = iterator.next().attr("alt");
                A_CodiceVolo[arrivi] = iterator.next().text();
                A_Citta[arrivi] = iterator.next().text();
                A_OraPrevista[arrivi] = iterator.next().text();
                A_OraStimata[arrivi] = iterator.next().text();
                A_StatoVolo[arrivi] = iterator.next().text();

            }
```

I can get all data... but i don't know how get the text in tag: alt="RYANAIR" and put the text here: A_Compagnia[1];
Someone is able to solve my problem!?
Thank you guys

Comment: Do you want `image url` or `Image title`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jSoup get title from img tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086644/jsoup-get-title-from-img-tag)

Comment: follow the link given above. you will do fine. let me know the progress

Comment: i don't understand it. I have tried with: Element e = doc.select("img[original-title]").first();
             String title = e.attr("original-title");
             System.out.println(title); but doesn't work. i don't understand how to implement this code in my code

Comment: Will you give me the URL from which you are fetching the title? So that i can help

Comment: There are various images. From which table you are trying to fetch the data?

Comment: See this`Elements img = doc.select("img");
                        String title = link.attr("alt");
`. Let me know the progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this  `Elements img = doc.select("img"); String title = link.attr("alt");` . Let me know the progress

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this.

```
ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();     
doc = Jsoup.connect("http:/url").timeout(10*1000).get(); 
     Element table = doc.select("table").first();
     for (Element row : table.select("td")) {
                        Elements column = row.select("img");
                        String title = column.attr("alt");
                        titles.add(title);
                        Log.i("All Titles",titles.toString());
                    }
```